# Как вернуть значение базы данных meta_value в Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, framework, wp-plugin

Есть wordpress фреймворк Unyson, работает на bootstrap. Поддерживает расширения и кастомные опции.
Имеется расширение Mega Menu, которое содержит 4 типа пунктов меню - item,column,row,default. Внутри каждого можно добавить свою опцию в виде асс. массива в моём случае :

```html
$options = array(
 'item_thumbnail' => array(
  'type'   => 'upload',
  'label'  => __( 'Image', 'fw' )
 ),
);
```

в тех. документации написано чтобы вернуть значение опции нужно вызвать хук `fw_ext_mega_menu_get_db_item_option($item_id, 'default')`
Но у меня возвращает пустую строку. Если я вызову массив опции default то он мне выдаёт

```html
array
(
    [item_thumbnail] => ''
)
```

Хотя в админке изображение сохранено и если обновить страницу, то оно есть. 
Я решил поискать опцию item_thumbnail в базе данных и нашёл meta_key

```html
fw:ext:mm:io:mysite
```

и meta_value к нему

```html
a:5:{s:4:"type";s:7:"default";s:3:"row";a:0:{}s:6:"column";a:0:{}s:4:"item";a:1:{s:5:"fakir";s:7:"default";}s:7:"default";a:1:{s:14:"item_thumbnail";a:2:{s:13:"attachment_id";s:2:"11";s:3:"url";s:49:"//mysite.loc/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/01.jpg";}}}
```

Тоесть значение в массиве опции default есть, и содержит в себе массив с ключом url и ссылкой на файл.
Как вернуть это значение?

Comment: Попробуйте напрямую мету читать https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_post_meta

Comment: Спасибо, пошел по вашему совету и решил свой вопрос! С рождеством!

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем решил так : `get_post_meta($item->ID);`
Дальше из массива нашел `fw:ext:mm:io:mysite`
И выгрузил опцию с url.

Весь код писать смысла нет, так как задействовано несколько файлов. 
Спасибо за наводку Владимиру!